# removing whitespace and \n from list in python?

Tags: python

```
list1= ['34 5\n', '67 37\n', '40 33\n', '99 100\n', '55 22']
```

the above is the list that i have, how can i make that to

```
['34','5','67','37','40','33','99','100','55','22']
```

I  want to remove the white space and '\n'. rstrip , strip , replace have been tried but none of the worked

```
list1.rstrip('\n')
list1.strip('\n')
list1.remove('\n')
```

Answer (score 7):

Use a pair of nested list comprehensions, the inner of which splits the strings on whitespace and the outer of which merges the nested lists together.

```
>>> list1= ['34 5\n', '67 37\n', '40 33\n', '99 100\n', '55 22']
>>> [x for sublist in [s.split() for s in list1] for x in sublist]
['34', '5', '67', '37', '40', '33', '99', '100', '55', '22']
```

Or, if this isn't to your liking, do it with loops instead. (This is probably clearer than a nested list comprehension, come to think of it.)

```
>>> result = []
>>> for s in list1:
    for num in s.split():
        result.append(num)

>>> result
['34', '5', '67', '37', '40', '33', '99', '100', '55', '22']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain
list2 = list(chain.from_iterable(map(str.split,list1)))
```

you can break this down to be somewhat more readable

```
flatten_list = chain.from_iterable
list_of_splits = map(str.split,list1) #essentially [s.split() for s in list1]
list2 = flatten_list(list_of_splits)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list2 = []
for item1 in list1:
    split_list = " ".split(item1)
    for item2 in split_list:
        list2.append(item2.rstrip())
```

Comment: this does not split the strings in each item.

Comment: if you split you dont need strip as it splits on one or more whitespaces